# Howler.js - var with several sounds. Cannot get it to play on onKeyDown event

Tags: javascript, events, playback, onkeydown, howler.js

I want to play several sound.wav files inside my project folder which includes HTML, CSS, JS and howler.js as lib. The idea is to create an array where keyboard letter correspond to wav files. Calling a function: "onKeyDown" and handing-over the pressed key should then play the specific wav-file. Unfortunately, it doesn't. Please have a look:

---

```js
var keyData = {
 a: {
  sound: new Howl({
   src: ['assets/guitarChords/a-major.wav']
  })
 },
 b: {
  sound: new Howl({
   src: ['assets/guitarChords/b-major.wav']
  })
 },
 c: {
  sound: new Howl({
   src: ['assets/guitarChords/c-major.wav']
  }) 
 },
 e: {
  sound: new Howl({
   src: ['assets/guitarChords/e-major.wav']
  }) 
 },
 g: {
  sound: new Howl({
   src: ['assets/guitarChords/g-major.wav']
  }) 
 } 
};

function onKeyDown(event) {

 if(event.key){
  keyData[event.key].sound.play();
 }

}
```

I tested this, like so:

```js
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['assets/guitarChords/a-major.wav']
});

sound.play();
```

And indeed, it played the sound.

Please help.

Comment: where are you adding the listener for keyDown?

Comment: I added: "document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event)" - it works....Cheers :)